# KeyAttribute not working on EF6 Code First when calling Enable-Migrations -Force

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to start a EF6 Code First project and even though all my entities have the Key attribute specified, some of then are not recognized when the command `Enable-Migrations -Force` is executed.

Here is an example:

```
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class StreetAddress : CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.IStreetAddress
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        [Column(Order=0)]
        public CIM.Data.EF.Status status { get; set; }
        CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.IStatus CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.IStreetAddress.status
        {
            get { return (CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.IStatus)status; }
            set { status = (CIM.Data.EF.Status)value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        [Column(Order=1)]
        public CIM.Data.EF.StreetDetail streetDetail { get; set; }
        CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.IStreetDetail CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.IStreetAddress.streetDetail
        {
            get { return (CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.IStreetDetail)streetDetail; }
            set { streetDetail = (CIM.Data.EF.StreetDetail)value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        [Column(Order=2)]
        public CIM.Data.EF.TownDetail townDetail { get; set; }
        CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.ITownDetail CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.IStreetAddress.townDetail
        {
            get { return (CIM.Data.IEC61968.Common.ITownDetail)townDetail; }
            set { townDetail = (CIM.Data.EF.TownDetail)value; }
        }
    }
```

And this is the output of the command (with a few cuts for brevity):

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -Force
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

CIM.Data.EF.StreetAddress: : EntityType 'StreetAddress' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
//... same message for a few other types ...
StreetAddresss: EntityType: EntitySet 'StreetAddresss' is based on type 'StreetAddress' that has no keys defined.
//... same message for a few other collections ...
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate()
//... some intermediate stack trace ...
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

CIM.Data.EF.StreetAddress: : EntityType 'StreetAddress' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
//... same message for a few other types ...
StreetAddresss: EntityType: EntitySet 'StreetAddresss' is based on type 'StreetAddress' that has no keys defined.
//... same message for a few other collections ...
```

Any hint on why the `[Key]` attribute is ignored? There are a few other types, all of them with composite keys, to which this also happen, but for others, also with composite keys, the attribute works.

Remark: This code was generated by a custom tool, but it compiles. Also, removing the explicit interface implementation does not help.

Comment: Most likely your problem comes from the fact that you are using composite objects in your primary key. Perhaps you're better of using a Guid or int.

Comment: @Hintham I suppose that too, but I'm implementing an external contract that cannot be changed. Those cases are compositions, so I'll try to model those entities in a different way, keeping the implementation of the interfaces.

Comment: Since you are using code first, what prevents you from adding an extra id field and use that as pk?

Comment: @Hintham I'm doing that right now. The issue indeed is with the composite objects. They should not be stored in separate tables anyway. They are value objects, not entities (in DDD terminology), and shoud have its fields included directly in the tables of the entities that are composed with them.